# Meteor Bootstrap Hamburger not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, navigation, responsive, hamburger-menu

my bootstrap navbar is not expanding and I am stuck as to why.

This functionality did work before, I'm not sure what change I made which stopped it from working, I think it was adding routing through iron:router.

My code for the navbar is just like the example docs:

```
<template name="navbar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <!-- Start of navbar -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" id="hamburgButton" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hamburg" aria-expanded="false">
                    <!-- Toggle Navigation -->
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/CC">ToastCalculator <!-- Site title -->
                </a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="hamburg">
                <!-- Menu itmes -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/CC">CC Calculator <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/CL">CL Calculator</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</template>
```

I even tried running a hack way of doing it (by removing the collapse class which makes it show up) but that didn't work either.

```
Template.navbar.events({ //responses to events
    'click #hamburgButton': function () {
        $('#hamburg') toggleClass("collapsed")
    }
});
```

I'm stuck

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: From what you've posted I'm not sure why this is happening. How are you importing Bootstrap to your application? Also, what did you change in the routing that you think may have caused the issue?

Comment: I am importing bootstrap by adding that package in Meteor using Meteor  add twbs:bootstrap. I'm not sure what exactly in the router is causing this issue but it has messed with other stuff too since I implemented it. Everything else from the bootstrap package is working fine.